# Insert many transations with one sql script

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a micro service which is using Liquibase to manage PostgreSQL table data. Into the table I have ~300 000 rows of data from `.sql` script. Inserting this number of records will take 3-4 hours.

What are the possible ways to delete all previous data in the table (probably with purge) and add new data without experiencing downtime?

For example, can I create a one transaction like this:

```
BEGIN;

  truncate table_name restart identity

  insert into table_name (column1, .., columnn) values (val1, ..valn), ..., (val1, ..valn)
  insert into table_name (column1, .., columnn) values (val1, ..valn), ..., (val1, ..valn)
  -- more 300 000 records


COMMIT;
```

What will happen if some software makes SQL query during script execution? Is it going to get all data? If SQL script fails, I would like to revert all previous data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to run a `DELETE` of all rows, followed by the `INSERT`s, all in the same transaction. That would allow concurrent reads, but concurrent data modifications would be blocked.

Loading a mere 300000 rows should be a matter of seconds, if all statements run in the same transaction and you don't have tons of indexes or slow triggers. Explore prepared statements and `COPY` to improve the load speed further.

An alternative method can be to prepare the new data in another schema. Then you need only a short interruption in which you rename the schemas or change `search_path`.

Comment: By ` concurrent data modifications would be blocked` you mean update sql statements?

Comment: `UPDATE`, but also `DELETE` or `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: I updated the post by adding a script. If I understand you correctly let's say if I start the script executed contacting purge of table data at the beginning and inserts after that this will take for example 5 min for execution. During this time another process will be able to make sql queries and get previous table data?

Comment: I get `ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
SQL state: 25P02`

Comment: Yes, after you deleted the data and while you are loading the new data, others will still be able to query the (deleted) old data. Then as soon as you `COMMIT` - poof! - all the new data become visible. The error is unrelated and caused by a previous error in the same transaction.